# What does $x$ represent?

Tags: notation

$x$ can mean:
A defined value in $x = 5$
An unknown, TBD. value, in $3x = 2+4$
A variable in $y(x) = x+4$
A sum of numbers in $\int_0^2 \mathrm{d}x$

Are there any other examples?

Comment: $x$ is a *variable*; there are different usages of it, but it is in any case a variable.

Comment: will this count $\sum_{x=0}$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't think it's a variable in the first two examples; it's a value and an unknown. A variable can be varied, but in those cases it cannot.

Comment: It is just a symbol used to represent whatever it means. There is nothing special about using $x$, except that it is commonly used.